# Making the page content in Wordpress dynamic

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Im new in wordpress and i would like to ask if there is a plugin in wordpress to edit its content dynamically? I've seen this [example](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/best-way-to-add-custom-dynamic-content-to-any-page) but i can't understand some if the codes provided. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you will have post and pages. Now you can create as many pages you want and they are they are displayed in page.php. For post types likes blog they can be changed in single.php. Also they are already dynamic from the admin panel. You can create/delete/update as many pages  and post you wish.